# Setting increasing ids in Django ChoiceField form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

Is there a way to change id values in Django ChoiceField forms?

For example I'd like my ChoiceField ids to output in the format `id="rating#"` where # is an incrementing number.  I assume you change the widget attributes for id, but how would I get the incrementing number in the id?

Example:

```
<label for="id_rating_0"><input type="radio" id="rating1" value="1" name="rating" /> </label>

<label for="id_rating_1"><input type="radio" id="rating2" value="2" name="rating" /> </label>

<label for="id_rating_2"><input type="radio" id="rating3" value="3" name="rating" /> </label>

<label for="id_rating_3"><input type="radio" id="rating4" value="4" name="rating" /> </label>

<label for="id_rating_4"><input type="radio" id="rating5" value="5" name="rating" /> </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `auto_id` form parameter doesn't do what you want, then I'm afraid I don't know what will:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#configuring-html-label-tags

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a forloop to render the choices manually

`<elem id="whatever_{{ forloop.counter }}"/>`